# BizTalk 2013 application can't seem to 'see' it's referenced assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, assemblies, biztalk-2013

I have a BizTalk 2013 application comprising of 3 projects - orchestration, schemas and maps.

In my orchestations project I have references to my maps and schemas projects within the same application.

However, when I try to select a map or schema using the referenced assemblies nothing is showing, not even the standard dll's such as System.XML or System.Configuration, the only thing I can see is Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.
I can see the references in the solution explorer but not when I try to use them in anywhere in the orchestration.

I had this problem before but can't remember how I resolved it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and re-creating the entire project which I seemed not to be able to reference everything is building and referencing as normal.  Not sure what caused it in the 1st place though, so still open to suggestions for that.
thanks

Comment: I think visual studio caches things. Try closing visual studio and reopening.

Comment: Yes, and sometimes you have to Clean first, close visual studio, open visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today. The only reference I was seeing was the XLANG.BaseTypes.
Turned out I set build action to none one time when I needed to test something and didn't need this orchestration. Setting it back to BtsCompile fixed it.